# How to use sqlite database of one device to other device live in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to use sqlite database of one device to multiple device. means that device will work as server and other mobile will access the database of that mobile.

Comment: Check Firebase for this kind of purpose

Comment: actually i dont want to use any internet connection

Comment: @matin sayyad,**SQLite strives to provide local data storage for individual applications and devices.**  It can not serve the purpose of client-server connectivity without Internet. for more details refer : [link](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Comment: @Priya Jagtap Thanx, i know it is different and challenging task but i want to find some way to do this

Comment: @matin sayyad, best of luck . I will definitely post if I found something helpful to you. Thank You.